# Where is Docker's buildkit setting?

Tags: docker, docker-buildkit

[image]

Here's my docker setup. However, there is no setup for the buildkit.

According to my docker image build log, bulidkit appears to be active.

```
[+] Building 28.8s (28/28) FINISHED
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                  0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 2.58kB                                                0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                     0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                       0.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                                    28.3s
 => => transferring context: 821.95MB                                                28.2s
...
...
```

**Where is Docker's buildkit setting?**

Comment: are you using wsl backend? This is docker-desktop right?

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/config/daemon/#configure-the-docker-daemon & https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cli/#configuration-files

Comment: What is your actual problem? I dont understand it.

Answer (score 1):

Docker Buildkit can either be enabled by setting an environment variable:

```
DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 docker build .
```

Or by setting it in the daemon configuration /etc/docker/daemon.json:

```
{ "features": { "buildkit": true } }
```

Indeed judging from your build log, you must have either one set.